# Autoscaling Linearlayout and TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Is there a way to auto-scale `Linearlayout` when `TextView` is too big? Like Facebook posts. When text or image is to large the layout is getting higher. I tried to do it via `xml` file but I didn't make it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

make the textview height wrap_conteent

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: It is wrap_content but the problem still exist.